# How does this definition give mutual independence of events?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am not understanding how this definition gives mutual independence:
[image]

I am not seeing this because It seems the LHS of the equation will always be the null set, as $B_i$ assumes both $A_i$ and $\bar{A_i} $, and the intersection of these is null, making the entire intersection whose probability we are computing on the LHS null. How am I misinterpreting this definition?

Comment: The symbol $B_i \in \{ A_i, \overline {A_i}  \}$ means that $B_i$ must be either ... or ...

Comment: $A,B,C$ are mutually independent when $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B),~\Pr(\overline{A}\cap B) = (1-\Pr(A))\times \Pr(B),\Pr(A\cap B\cap C) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)\times \Pr(C),~\Pr(A\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C})=\Pr(A)\times (1-\Pr(B))\times(1-\Pr(C)),\dots$

Comment: That is, from $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots,A_n$... pick any subset of these.  Then replace any from the selected subset with their complements as desired.  The probability of the intersection of these will be the product of the probabilities.

Comment: I don't think that Definition 14.5 actually matches @JMoravitz's correct description of mutual independence.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree since it fails to talk about that it should hold for all subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

Comment: Yes, and to be clear: the OP is not really asking what it means for events to be mutually independent; they are specifically trying to clarify the given definition.

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand side you can get sets in the probability such as $A_1\cap A_2\cap \overline{A_3}$. So each $B_1$ is either $A_1$ or $\overline{A_1}$, $B_2$ is either $A_2$ or $\overline{A_2}$, and so on. So as the $A_i$ are distinct and none are complements of another, you aren't getting a set and its complement. The intersection can still be empty, if any of the sets are disjoint or if one is a subset of another, but that's allowed to happen.

Comment: so when the definition says "for all", they are referring to the $i$, and are not saying for all elements belong to the set {$A_i, \bar{A_i}$}?