# How to show these 2 definitions of mutual independence are equivalent?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, independence

I am endeavoring to show that these 2 definitions of mutual independence are equivalent:

> **Definition 14.4** Events $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are said to be mutually independent if for every subset $I \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with size $|I| \geq 2$,
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left[\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i\right]=\prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}\left[A_i\right]
> $$
> **Definition 14.5** Events $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are said to be mutually independent if for all  $B_i \in${$A_i, \bar{A_i}$}$,i= 1,\ldots, n,$
> $$\mathbb{P}\left[B_1 \cap \cdots \cap B_n\right]=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left[B_i\right]$$

This was an optional exercise in my lecture. By showing these definitions to be equivalent, I took this to mean that for any set of events in any sample space, these definitions either both say these events are independent or both don't say these events are independent. So far, I have showed that $A$ and $B$ being independent implies that $A$ and $\bar{B}$ are independent, and $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ are independent. However, the difficulty with which I am faced is that when showing how definition 14.5 saying that a set of events is independent implies how definition 14.4 also says that these events are independent, I am at a loss to show how small subsets of $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ such as $A_1, A_2$ have the probability of their intersection be the product of their probabilities from how in $A_1, \ldots, A_n$, every single event here has this property, with some of these perhaps being the complements. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789782/how-does-this-definition-give-mutual-independence-of-events?noredirect=1#comment10183853_4789782) I clarified that definition 14.5 means that $i$ assumes all of the values in $1, \ldots, n$, which is the main thing I am having an issue with here- relating the entire set to a small subset. I would appreciate help on showing the equivalence between these definitions.

Comment: hint: $P(\bar{A}\cap B)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(B)-P(A)P(B)=(1-P(A))P(B)=P(\bar{A})P(B)$, where the second equality follows from independence between A and B. So you can (without loss of generality) assume $B_i=\bar{A}_i$ for $i\le k$ and $B_i=A_i$ for $k<i\le n$, and treat one event $B_i$ at a time to separate the probabilities of these events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $n$ mutually independent events as defined from definition 14.5, it follows that any subset of size $n-1$ of these are mutually independent as well as per definition 14.4 as seen as

$$\begin{array}{rl}\Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1}) &= \Pr(A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1}\cap A_n) + \Pr(A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_{n-1}\cap \overline{A_n})\\&=\Pr(A_1)\cdots\Pr(A_{n-1})\Pr(A_n) + \Pr(A_1)\cdots\Pr(A_{n-1})(1-\Pr(A_n))\\&=\Pr(A_1)\cdots\Pr(A_{n-1})\end{array}$$

By relabeling we see it works for any $n-1$ of the events, not just the first $n-1$.  By backwards induction we see that it also follows that any smaller subset of the events also will be mutually independent.